# Using external library in incremental source generator

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I am trying to reference DotLiquid in an incremental source generator. I have no compilation errors. However, in runtime I get "Could not load file or assembly 'DotLiquid, Version=2.2.692.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82e46016ecf9f07c'. The system cannot find the file specified." How I can fix it ?

I've tried to use approach from [Source Generators Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md)

My generator's csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

        <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
        <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>

        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>

        <PackageReference Include="DotLiquid" Version="2.2.692" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
        <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
        <None Include="$(PkgDotLiquid)\lib\netstandard2.0\*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
        
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers"
                          Version="3.3.4">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.6.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces"
                          Version="4.6.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My incremental source generator:

```
using DotLiquid;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;


namespace SourceGenerators1;

[Generator]
public class TestGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{

    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        var template = Template.Parse("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the DotLiquid assembly actually turn up alongside your analyser assembly in the nuget cache, when restored into a project?

Comment: @pjc50, if I understand your question correctly, there is no DotLiquid dll in SourceGenTest/SourceGenTest/SourceGenTest/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0

Comment: @pjc50, I've found a way to include DotLiquid assembly by using <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>. However, it still doesn't work.